# How to connect second screen to pc/mac wirelessly in extend mode?

Tags: wireless-networking, multiple-monitors, chromecast

I want to find a way to connect my mac with my second screen wirelessly. Solutions like Google Chromecast gives you the option to mirror screen but not extend to a second screen which will give you more workspace.

Are you aware of any way that I can achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not a current solution but a future one is https://airtame.com/features#banner

which has this feature included in its future releases but is significantly more expensive than Google Chromecast.

Adding it as an answer for anyone interested on it.